# MetaMask - RPC Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Hash

Tags: metamask, etherscan

I am using this code below and I got an error:

```
await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(this.state.transactionHash, (err, txReceipt)=>{
          console.log(err,txReceipt);
          this.setState({txReceipt})
        }); //await for getTransactionReceipt

        await this.setState({transactionHash: this.state.txReceipt.transactionHash});
        await this.setState({blockNumber: this.state.txReceipt.blockNumber});
        await this.setState({gasUsed: this.state.txReceipt.gasUsed});
```

The error is:

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type common.Hash
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: Which version of web3 are you using? What is the value of transactionHash?

Comment: I am using web3@1.2.6 and the value of transaction hash is '0x29c680fb90517d2611eb8856b8ce6f645574a9dad77584c21b76a052a2d6e1d8'

Comment: I'd suggest trying different versions of web3, like 1.2.5, 1.2.4 or similar. And create an issue for web3 developers with a reproducible case.

Comment: @Ismael I have tried 1.2.4 and 1.2.5 versions , still give me same error.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to test because the hash doesn't exist in a public blockchain. Similar error happened to me and it was a bug inside web3, so it doesn't have a workaround. Create a reproducible test and report as an issue or debug it and report your findings

Answer (score 2):

I may probably be late to this thread but I think this may be useful for others.
I also encountered a similar issue that lead me to this thread in search of answers.

In my case, I was attempting to get the account balance of an ethereum account like so:

```
provider.request({
          method: "eth_getBalance",
          params: [wallet.address], "latest"],
        });
```

But I actually passed a wrong value (wallet.address - *This value was null*) in the first index of the params property which resulted in the error.

The correct snippet is shown below:

```
provider.request({
          method: "eth_getBalance",
          params: [wallet.accounts[0], "latest"],
        });
```

Hence, for subsequent devs who encounter such issues, this may simply be due to a wrong value being provided.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This was my exact case!!!